# Replacing multiple elements of an array while keeping their position

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

Helo guys, I am pretty new to `javascript` so I seek your help.
My problem is the following:

If have an array like

```
     var arr1 = ["a", "b", "a" "c"];
```

and I'd like to find and replace each "a" with a certain element of an other array

```
     var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,];
```

Now how do I replace each "a" with the first element of arr2?
Each "b" with the second and so on.

Is there any possibility of this? With keeping the the position?

Comment: so, the result array should looks like this `[1,2,1,3]`  ?

Comment: unclear how "a" "b" relates to 1 and 2

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yes it should look like that.

Comment: @epascarello I define it how it relates, but its also good if i replace all "a"s with a variable.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write any code to accomplish this yourself? Please post it if you want debugging help

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have tried to use the for loop, however I failed so miserably I wouldn't like to post it.

Comment: @PéterSzabó-tóth What you are looking is arr1 to be [1,2,1,3] 0r [1,2,3,4]??

Comment: @PéterSzabó-tóth still unclear, is it "b" the second index because it happens to be the second letter that you came upon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an object to associate each character to a specific integer: `obj`:

```
const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};
```

Then use the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to remap the array `arr1` with the helper object `obj`:

```
arr1.map(e => obj[e])
```

> The [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];

const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};

console.log(
  arr1.map(e => obj[e])
)
```

---

This way you can change the relationship between the characters and number in by changing `obj`. You can even set variables as values of `obj`, for example:

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];
const otherLetter = "z";
const obj = {a:otherLetter, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6};

console.log(
  arr1.map(e => obj[e])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynmaic approach and build succesive a hash table and take that value.

```js
var array1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"],
    array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    index = 0;
    result = array1.map(v => v in hash ? hash[v] : hash[v] = array2[index++]);

console.log(result);
```

A version without `index`, but with mutating `array2`

```js
var array1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"],
    array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array1.map(v => v in hash ? hash[v] : hash[v] = array2.shift());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "f"];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//print out arrays
console.log("arr1: ", arr1);
console.log("arr2: ", arr2);

//loop through the arr1
var i;
//loop until you reach the length of array1.
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  //check type of item in arr1
  switch (arr1[i]) {
    case "a":
      arr1[i] = arr2[0];
      break;
    case "b":
      arr1[i] = arr2[1];
      break;
    case "c":
      arr1[i] = arr2[2];
      break;
    default:
      //default if none of the above cases match with entry in array1
      arr1[i] = -1;
  }
}

//print out arrays
console.log("arr1: ", arr1);
console.log("arr2: ", arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to generate indices from the characters in `arr1` like this:

```
let indices = arr1.map(str => parseInt(str, 36) - 10);
```

The second argument of `parseInt` is the radix, 36 allows for specifying numbers using `0-9` and `a-z`. Because `a = 10` we need to substract 10 in order to get the proper index (`a` -> index `0`).

And then use these indices to get the according element from `arr2`:

```
let result = indices.map(index => arr1[index]);
```

A small, condensed example:

```js
let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = arr1.map(s => parseInt(s, 36) - 10).map(i => arr2[i]);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string representation of the `arr1` and replace the characters:

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,];
var str = arr1.join(',');
arr2.forEach((number, index)=>{
  var character = arr1[index];
  if(character && isNaN(arr1[index])){
      var re = new RegExp(character,"g");
      str = str.replace(re, number);
  }
});

arr1 = str.split(',');
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my (much simpler) answer:

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];

//I'd like to find and replace each "a" 
//with a certain element of an other array
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,];  

for(var i in arr1) {
  arr1[i] = arr2[arr1[i].charCodeAt(0) - 97];
}
console.log('arr1 is now: [' + arr1 + ']');
```

Comment: Simpler but cannot handle anything but single letters

Comment: That was the question.  If it was numbers, then the code would be different. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var arr1 = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];
    var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
         
    var uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(arr1));
    for(i=0;i<uniqueItems.length;i++){
      arr1.forEach(function(item, j) { if (item == uniqueItems[i]) arr1[j] = arr2[i]; });
    }

    console.log(arr1);
```